# Getting an Internal Server Error while editing the ROSwiki

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
I was editing the ROS wiki for a package I'm working on, and I think I was somehow editing it in 2 separate tabs. It seems to have completely broken the page though, and now I can't access it at all. The package I'm working on is opencupboard_action. Please let me know what I should do.
Thanks
Annie

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12315/getting-an-internal-server-error-while-editing-the-roswiki/) by [annieHolladay](https://answers.ros.org/users/1525/annieholladay/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-12-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have restored the page.  There was an error in the Parameters specification.  I've never seen that cause an Internal Server Error before, though, so we'll look into making that more robust.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-12-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0